# Why do I need multi-catch blocks when Java exits the try block when the first error is encountered?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

When the run time error occurs it exits the try block. It will throw only one exception and enter the catch block. Then why do I need multiple catch blocks? Where are multi-catch blocks used?

Also, I can also use `Throwable` to catch any exception. Is that right?

Comment: @Turing85 An MRE of what? This is a conceptual question; it's not about a particular program.

Comment: Since when does the compiler throw an exception? What you mean is a runtime exception. The compiler has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As soon the run time error occurs it leaves the try block[throws only one error object], then why there is a concept called multi-catch block? since one error will be thrown, it is enough to have a single catch right!!!

Comment: @LukasNothhelfer Eh, you're being kinda nitpicky. I've edited out the word "compiler".

Comment: It's not really nit-picky, though perhaps the comment could have been better phrased.  it's essential to successful programming to understand where compilation leaves off and the actual execution of your program begins.

Comment: Note that you _should not_ catch anything unless _you know how to usefully handle it_ (such as by retrying for `IOException`). In particular, catching `Throwable` will prevent serious JVM errors from being handled properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use a multi catch block to in order to catch different types of exceptions. Let's say you have a custom exception MyCoolExn that implements Throwable.

```
try {
    // run piece of code
} catch (MyCoolExn e) { // catching your custom exception
    System.out.println("custom exception occurred");
} catch (Throwable e) { // catch any other exception
    System.out.println("an unknown exception occurred ");
}
```

Note that the order of the blocks is important. If you swap them, MyCoolExn will never be caught, as the Trowable block will catch everything

Comment: This is a good example, though in "real programming" it's likely the exception handler will be doing something more involved than merely printing out a message, and what it's doing will often depend on the specific exception - which is why you want multiple catch blocks.

Comment: But I think that in java version from JDK 7, it provides a new feature called multi-catch (i.e) catching multiple exceptions in a single catch block, in that you cannot use a same type added with a base class type like,  [catch(MyCoolExn | Throwable)]     https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/multiple-exceptions -->Example-4

Comment: See my answer; the point of "catch (X ex)" and "catch (Y ex)" clauses is to allow different actions to be done for different exceptions.  The "catch (X | Y ex)" syntax allows you to do the same action for different exceptions.

Comment: @KavinVelusamy, yes, but that is when you want to catch multiple (unrelated by subtyping) exception in the same block, which will handle them in a same way. Exceptions for a multi-catch try block (which should be used when exceptions should be handled differently) can be subtypes of each other. You should usually have the base Exception class at the end, so you catch any exception. If you have it before any superclass, then the superclass catch block is redundant, as the Exception one is matched first

Answer (score 1):

The 'compiler' isn't doing any of this; the compiler is not around. Exceptions are a runtime phenomenon.

Your question appears to be asking how the runtime exception dispatcher picks an exception handler: it is based on type matching.

When you say 'enter **the** catch block', that is not correct. It selects the first catch-block whose argument type is assignment-compatible with the exception actually thrown.

If you always write `catch (Exception ex)` then this will catch any exception, since `Exception` is a superclass of all exception types, and if this is the first such catch block no other will be considered.  But this is not always an appropriate exception-handling style; you may be advised to be more specific.

Perhaps this is a good way to understand multiple catch-blocks: you're saying "if it's an X-type exception then do this; otherwise if it's a Y-type exception then do this other thing; otherwise if it's a Z-type exception then a third thing".

FWIW, you rarely want to write `catch (Throwable th)` unless you're fully aware of the mechanisms you're interfering with by so doing.